# Как создать pdf-файл и отправить его по eMail с использованием Spring MVC^?

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf, java, email

На сервере должен автоматически формироваться файл отчета в формате pdf и посылаться по eMail.

1. Какие есть возможности для форматирования информации в этом отчете (надо рисовать графики и таблицы)? Может, Spring предоставляет какие-то специальные классы?
2. Как прикрепить этот файл в отправляемому еМail?

Answer (score 1):

Про PDF смотрите тут: [Как выполнить печать на бланке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/366417)

А письмо можно каким-нибудь банальным JavaMail API отправить.